# How to skip ansible roles for certain servers

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have following code wherein I have 3 roles as below. I do not want to execute "def" role for hosts which has group_name "er". So when servers also belong to "er" group, skip def role.

```
hosts: qw
vars:
roles:
  abc
  def
  fgh
```

Comment: Does [Conditionals with `roles`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-with-roles) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Conditionals with roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-with-roles)

```yaml
- hosts: qw
  vars:
  roles:
    - role: abc
    - role: def
      when: 'er' not in group_names
    - role: fgh
```

Something like that would likely work for your usecase.